# Problem with Adapter class, no crash, but page freezes and reloads

Tags: java, android, adapter

In my CommentAdapter.java class I have the following code. When a user leaves a comment on a certain post the image icon has to change from the black chat icon to the yellow chat icon. Works fine. The problem arises when a user deleted the comment that they left on the post. If they delete their comment and there are no other comments from that user for that post the chat icon should be changed back from yellow to black.

It works and I get the desired result, but for some reason it throws a null pointer, the page freezes, reloads, and then it takes me back to the home page with desired result. I need for the entire process to run smoother obviously without any null pointers.

And yes, obviously I know what null pointers are and how to fix them, but here I can't understand why I am getting it. Chat icon exists and all.

Crash line marked with arrow below.

**CommentAdapter**

```
public class CommentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CommentAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ImageView mImageView;

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Comment> mComment;
    private String postid;
    private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;

    public CommentAdapter(Context mContext, List<Comment> mComment, String postid) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mComment = mComment;
        this.postid = postid;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.comment_item, parent, false);
        return new CommentAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        final Comment comment = mComment.get(position);

        holder.comment.setText(comment.getComment());
        getUserInfo(holder.image_profile, holder.username, comment.getPublisher());

 holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(final View v) {
                if (comment.getPublisher().equals(mFirebaseUser.getUid())) {

                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Do you want to delete this comment?");
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "No",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    Log.d("POSTID ->", postid);
                                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Comments").child(postid).child(comment.getCommentid())
                                            .setValue(null).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
   -------------------------------------------> mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_chat_black);
                                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Your comment has been deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

 public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView image_profile, imageView;
        public TextView username, comment;

        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            image_profile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
            comment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentPost);
        }
    }
```

**Logcat**

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.e.events, PID: 18463
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.e.events.Adapter.CommentAdapter$3$2$1.onComplete(CommentAdapter.java:110)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)

Comment: use holder.mImageView instead of mImageView

Comment: @MayankBhatnagar Same result, still get the np

Comment: is this imageview is in your row xml? add your viewholder class as well

Comment: My ImageView is in my post_item.xml and CommentAdapter.java inflates comment_item.xml. Okay, I added the ViewHolder

Answer (score 0):

If your Comment class is a custom class, I suggest storing the image resource value in the Comment class itself then refreshing the Adapter when you alter the Comment's image value. It should look something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position){
    // ...

    final Comment comment = mComment.get(position);

    // Use a getter you defined in your Comment class to set the ViewHolder's image
    // (Make sure your ViewHolder class has an ImageView in it for this to work)
    // *(Also, make sure your Comment class already has a default Image Resource
    // value assigned within it)
    holder.myImageView.setImageResource(comment.getImgResource());

    // ...
}
```

Then inside of your Callback, where you were setting the Image Resource previously:

```
if(task.isSuccessful){
    // Update the image resource stored in the Comment
    comment.setImgResource(myNewImageResource);

    // Anything else you want to do ...

    notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notify the adapter to refresh
}
```